# How to know which team that repository belong to in github using github restful API

Tags: github, repository, devops, github-api

I need to know which team and child team does this repository belong to using github api

I can get repos under organization

```
GET /orgs/:org/repos
```

the format of the url when I clone is:

```
https://github.com/organization/repo-name.git
```

I need create directory by team name for repository management,
but I don't know that getting parent team and child team by repository name

For example: I have a repository

```
https://github.com/organization/repo-name.git
```

the repository belong to following team:

```
IT_department/web/Java
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with python specifically, but to do with looking up github api

Answer (score 0):

You can get the child teams using the below curl :

```
curl -H "Authorization: token personal_access_token" -X GET https://api.github.com/teams/:team_id/teams
```

Then go to the respective team and get the team_id.

pass this team_id to list the Repos under the child team.
curl:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token personal_access_token" -X GET https://api.github.com/teams/:team_id/repos
```

the above curl will list all the Repos under the child team.

If you want to check if the Repository exists in the team then you can use the below curl:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token personal_access_token" -X GET https://api.github.com/teams/:team_id/repos/:owner/:repo
```